# maximize the values of given variables.

Tags: calculus, optimization, numerical-methods, maxima-minima, interpolation

i have function A in two variables A(x,y) whose value is known.
i have been provided with a table having some values of A at a particular value of x and y that is  A(x1,y1) = some integer (for example)

| A | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | value1 | value 1 |
| Second | value2 | value2 |

(table is just to explain data format)

I need to find the value of x and y where the A has the maximum value and also the maximum value of A by using a minimum of data provided that is provided in the table.

So my question is  :

1. Do I need to formulate the equation for A.
2. What is the method to solve such a problem.
   please mention all method if know them, so that I will find the best one as per the use case.

P.S: I can use computer for calculation if any method requires it.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood correctly, but can't you just look at all values of the A-column in your data, find the one that is largest, and then read off the x,y values next to it?

Comment: no you misunderstood me! I will try to ask this question more clearly.